# uwsgi memory usage optimisation

Tags: django, memory-usage, uwsgi

I'm running several django sites on uwsgi, and I'm attempting to optimise my configuration for memory usage, but the --idle and --die-on-idle flags don't seem to be doing anything.

Each daemon starts off at around 10-12MB and increases to around 30MB once it has served a request, but then stays there even when idle for some time. My startup command is:

```
uwsgi --cheap --idle 60 --die-on-idle --http :8083 --wsgi-file /var/django/mysite/apache/django.wsgi
```

Is there anything I'm missing here? From the docs, I'd expect the "--idle" flag to make it drop back to its initial memory usage after 60 seconds of idleness; and I'd expect the 
"--die-on-idle" flag to kill the worker process completely at that point. Neither of these happen, although the "--cheap" flag does seem to work.

(Note: I realise http isn't the best protocol but I want to get the memory issue sorted before I recompile nginx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need the master process to have those options working. If you want to use the http protocol, use --http-socket instead of --http (that will create another process).
In addition to this give a look at KSM on the uWSGI wiki

Comment: Cheers, --master was what I needed. I must say the docs are a bit lacking in detail!